# Using Object Detection API on local GPU but not last version (v2.5.0)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, object-detection-api, cudnn

I am trying to use my local GPU to train an `EfficientDetD0` model. I already have a good pipeline (that works on Google Colab for example), I modified it a bit to use it locally, but one problem happens every time I launch the training.

I use conda to install `tensorflow-gpu` with `cuda` and `cudnn` but it makes `TensorFlow v2.4.1` environments and when I launch the training the Object Detection API automatically install `TensorFlow V2.5.0`. So my env is not using the gpu for the training because `cuda` and `cudnn` are waiting for `TensorFlow` to be `v2.4.1` and not `v2.5.0`.

Is there a way to get the Object Detection API in `v2.4.1` and not `v2.5.0` ?

I tried many things but it doesn't work (training is failing or going for CPU training).

Here is the code that install dependencies and overwrite `TensorFlow` version to `TensorFlow` `v2.5.0`:

```py
os.system("cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .")
os.system("python -m pip install .")
```

SYSTEM:

- gpu : Nvidia RTX 3070
- os : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- tensorflow: 2.4.1

P.S.: I go with `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu` for installing `TensorFlow`, `cuda` and `cudnn` in my training env because manually there was a dependency problem, so I took the easy way.

**EDIT : solution found explained in comments.**

Comment: I found a solution to my problem by installing all lastest packages for cuda and cudnn and not using conda env (even base) but my default pc env. That works really well now, that was dumb, but took me 1 week to figure it out :D

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install specific version of tensorflow gpu

```
1. Set Up Anaconda Environments
conda create -n tf_gpu cudatoolkit=11.0

2. Activate the new Environment
source activate tf_gpu

3. Install tensorflow-gpu 2.4.1
pip install tensorflow==2.4.1
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the initial problem. Object detection API will automatically overwrite the version by installing TensorFlow v2.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run object_detection without "installing" it. Dont run setup.py. Just setup the neccesery paths and packages manually.

Or edit the setup.py to skip installing the specific verison of TF. I quess that this version is a requirement of some of the packages installed in setup.py.

I use the object_detection without running the setup.py or doing any "installation" without any problems.